# Soap service - measuring response time

Tags: java, performance, soap

I'm looking to measure the response time of a SOAP service from the time that the request is received (the soap message is demarshalled) to the point just before the response (that will go back to the client) will be marshalled. I'm looking for some tips on how to accurately measure this? I don't suppose it matters that it's a SOAP service. Regardless, should I just use a timer or is there a tool out there that would suffice? I'm using JAX-WS and using the application server that ships with JAX-WS for testing web services, so I haven't picked a web server yet.

Comment: How are you exposing your services? EJB's? Raw JAX-WS? Other?

Comment: JAX-WS. Sorry about that

Comment: What is the rationale behind excluding SOAP marshalling/unmarshalling from the time measured?

Comment: The reason is because im only concerned with measuring the time it takes for my service logic to execute for a given value. So, im not concerned with how long soap marshalling takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet container is likely to offer you an option to log the time taken to process each request on the server. In tomcat this is done by registering a valve in server.xml:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
   directory="/var/www/logs"  prefix="access_" 
   suffix=".log" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b, t=%D" 
   resolveHosts="false"/>
```

`t=%D` will show `t=xx`, where xx is the time taken (in millis). The element should be nested in your `<Host>` element.

If you want to measure *only* the processing time, without any request handling, marshalling, etc. then you need some AOP / interceptor / filter. It depends very much on your technology stack, but in either [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), [EJB](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html) or [CDI](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html) you can have interceptors around your services.

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this include the time taken to demarshall the soap request? The reason I ask is that I do not wish to include the time taken to demarshal when a request arrives at the server. I'm only interested in measuring the time taken to perform the service operation.

Comment: it includes all the processing - dermarshalling, processing, marlshalling. See update for only the processing